# multiselect element and styling selected option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiselect element rendered like

```
<button class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" style=" title="None selected">
<span class="multiselect-selected-text">None selected</span>
<b class="caret"></b>
</button>
```

When rendered on default you can see that `None selected` title is set. On select action this will ofcourse change to title of selected element.

> My question is: how can I using css target `None selected` and
>   followed `caret` to be `font-color: gray;` and if something else is
>   selected to change `font-color` to `black` for example?

**update:
I tried using :contains selector like suggested and in this very simple scenario I'm getting always true (alert a)**

```
 if ($(".multiselect-selected-text:contains('xxxxxx')")) {
       alert('a');
    } else {
       alert('b');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector in Jquery. Try this

```
 $('.multiselect-selected-text:contains("None selected")').parent().addClass('grayOut');
```

Css rule

```
.grayOut{
  color: gray;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/r9xuys28/1/)**

And ofcource you need to execute the above script on change event of the multiselect plugin.

Comment: @user1765862 `($(".multiselect-selected-text:contains('xxxxxx')"))` will return a element if the condition satisfies, else it will return `[]` which is `defined` and hence your if loop executes. To validate it properly try this `$(".multiselect-selected-text:contains('xxxxxx')").length != 0`